# Best way to make cross-origin requests using cookies for own application in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http, google-chrome-extension, gmail, attachment

I am making an ASP.NET application and would like to be able for my file upload to allow attachments to be dragged straight from Gmail. The problem is that I cannot load the data from the links dragged in because of cross-origin rules.

There are 2 problems:

- First, cross-origin rules prevent me from making requests to the gmail attachment server.
- Second, even if I were to make the request with cross-origin, the cookies would not be included.

I am using Chrome and only interested in doing this on my own computers.

One option is I could make a Chrome extension which allows cross-origin requests but only from my website.

Another option would be for my locally hosted server to communicate with Chrome to make the request itself.

Which of these would be the best option and how would I do it?

Comment: what cookies do you need from the gmail tab?

Comment: the ones that are needs to use the gmail attachments. It says it uses `google.com`, `mail.google.com`, `googleusercontent.com` and `mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com`. Ideally, it would just be an application the user would download and it would just use the cookies from Chrome so they wouldn't have to go through any setup.

Comment: you need the cookies cause it says the URLs you could be getting the images from? or is there some other information in them

Comment: @NoamYizraeli They would be mostly pdfs. The link of the attachment just leads directly to the file so I just need a way to use Chrome in headless mode to access the file.

Comment: @NoamYizraeli, to be clear, yes the cookies are needed but I would like them to be gotten automatically from Chrome.

Comment: Try to use wget or backend to call it.

Comment: @JohnTribe, how do I get Google Chrome's cookies when making the http request?

Comment: @trinalbadger587 DevTools->Application->Cookies->website

Comment: @trinalbadger587 or use Cookie Chrome plugin